# Page URL appearing in Twitter Post - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

So I was following the twitter dev steps in order to create a twitter button for my website, which I do not want.

Here is what I have-

```
<script>
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
 t = window.twttr || {};
if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

t._e = [];
t.ready = function (f) {
t._e.push(f);
};

return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

And here is what is in my div-

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
        href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I%20just%20voted pic.twitter.com/95KaxlgCV4"
        data-size="large">Tweet</a>
```

For some reason the actual pop up that comes up to show what I'm posting is adding in the localhost URL in and I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `data-url` attribute equal to a whitespace it will remove the URL from the end of the tweet. You can also put the text in a `data-text` attribute to avoid having to encode it.

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" data-text="I just voted pic.twitter.com/95KaxlgCV4" data-url=" " data-size="large">
```

More info [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters#button)